How can I make simple https wrapper around a server in python3?
I want to imitate a https website, but I want a path to correspond to a custom input. E.g. https://example.com/ returns the normal website, but https://example.com/custom/path/here returns my custom path. But I need to return it over https. I would prefer an example, not just a link to the docs.
